# Challenge: How to find the secret key in homebrew MAC/keyed hash: sha1(key + cookie)?

Tags: hash, attacks, salt, sha, design-flaw

I am trying to solve a security challenge on a website.

Basically, the website computes `sha1(key + cookie)` to sign a cookie so that the user can't change it himself, and to accomplish the goal you have to find the `key` value.

I have two (not really good) ideas to find the secret key value :

- **1: Online** (way too slow) try all combinations of the authentication hash with an empty (0 bytes) cookie: this way the website will compute `sha1(key)` only and will stop displaying an error when I find the correct secret key value.
- **2: Offline** (still very slow but better since you don't need any network requests) go on the website and get {cookie, cookie_hash}. Try to hash `xxx + cookie` for every possible value of `xxx` : when `sha1(xxx + cookie) == cookie_hash`, I know that xxx == secret key.

The thing is, as you noticed, that even the second method is brute forcing and therefore very slow.

Do you think there is a faster method?

Comment: How long of a secret are we talking about here? (For that matter, how long is the cookie value?) GPUs can brute-force SHA1 at an astonishing rate, but you're still going to have a hard time brute-forcing more than a few billion values, meaning 30-odd bits of entropy. That's not a lot.

Comment: Judging by the passwords / keys used in the other challenges, I'd say less that 10 characters (at least less than 15) composed of letters (including capitals) and numbers.

Comment: I don't mean to be 'that guy', but a lot of those 'l3rn 2 h4xx' sites use very easy passwords, if it's not on google already and you don't know the cookie/salt I'd just brute force it all at once, it will give you the password+salt, then just remove one letter from the end of the string, try it, repeat until it says you're right.

Mind sharing the site you're on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and to accomplish the goal you have to find the key value.

Do you *really* need to recover the key to accomplish the goal?

The scheme you have described is vulnerable to the classic [length extension attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack) where a hash function is misused as a message authentication code. The attack is described very well in the Wikepedia article so I shall avoid replicating the example here.

With the length extension attack, you can generate a valid signature without knowing the actual key value, which is presumably enough to solve the challenge.

Comment: I think that can indeed do the trick. Thank you very much!